# Gitlab CI: how to set version number for Yocto recipes

Tags: gitlab-ci, yocto

I am building a Linux image using Yocto with gitlab pipeline. I need to embed a version into the image. Is using an environment variable a good way to do this? The only way I can see the value of the variable later on is by echoing it in my yml, which means I have to drill into the log to find the info.

Is there a better way to do this?

I was wondering if I should set it into the yml each time as this is easy to see. But it feels wrong to change the .yml so often.

Comment: Your question seems somewhat opinion-based, which is not very well-suited for Stackoverflow questions. Consider rewording your question to deal with a specific problem, rather than asking for an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use the same techniques for versioning any piece of software with GitLab CICD.

> But it feels wrong to change the .yml so often.

Your intuition seems right here. It would be unusual, for example, to see the CI yaml edited just to accommodate each release. Most pipeline definitions are written in such a way that many releases of different versions can be made using the same pipeline YAML definition.

There are many ways to approach this.

You might do something like using `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` so that you control the version and release by pushing a tag (or creating a release), `$CI_PIPELINE_IID`, `$CI_JOB_ID` or similar for versioning. You could also use a user-provided variable to a manual pipeline or manual job within a pipeline instead of editing the YAML. If you use changelogs, you could also make a script to read a versioned CHANGELOG entry to find the version. If you want to automate semantic versioning, there's also a whole host of automated semver tools out there.

See GitLab's recent blog entry [*Tutorial: Automate releases and release notes with GitLab*](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/11/01/tutorial-automated-release-and-release-notes-with-gitlab/) for some examples of this.